# Feature linked annotation subtype removal in migrating to ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, annotation, migration

I have a question about emergent properties of deleting an annotation subtype.  If we delete an annotation subtype how will this effect the annotation feature class, will there be any changes to the visible annotation the active data frame?  I haven’t seen any changes with the removal of the subtype, but it seems too good to be true.

Background info:

In our enterprise implementation, we are in the process of upgrading from a 9.2 to 10 data format, to help achieve this we came up with a Python script, turns out there are quite a few databases that fail at the  arcpy.UpgradeGDB_management() method.  The exception is:"The feature class' default subtype code cannot be retrieved or is invalid” In order to resolve this issue we removed the Annotation’s subtype and the script will run just fine.

Thanks in advance.